# How to display jQuery Validation error container only on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the [Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) work. It works fine for individual fields, but when I try to include the demo code for the error container that contains all of the errors, I have an issue. The problem is that it shows the container with all errors when I am in all fields, but I would like to display the error container only when the user presses the submit button (but still show inline errors beside the control when losing focus).

The problem is the message in the container.  When I took off the code as mentioned in the answer below for the container, the container output just displays the number of errors in plain text.

What is the trick to get a list of detailed error messages?  What I would like is to display "ERROR" next to the control in error when the user presses the tab button, and to have a summary of everything at the end when he presses submit. Is that possible?

**Code with all input from here:**

```
    $().ready(function() {
        var container = $('div.containererreurtotal');

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#frmEnregistrer").bind("invalid-form.validate", function(e, validator) {
          var err = validator.numberOfInvalids();
          if (err) {
            container.html("THERE ARE "+ err + " ERRORS IN THE FORM")
            container.show();
          } else {
            container.hide();
          }
        }).validate({
                    rules: {
                            nickname_in: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4
                            },
                            prenom_in: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4
                            },
                            nom_in: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4
                            },
                            password_in: {
                                    required: true,
                                    minLength: 4
                            },
                            courriel_in: {
                                    required: true,
                                    email: true
                            },
                            userdigit: {
                                    required: true
                            }
                    },
                    messages: {
                            nickname_in: "ERROR",
                            prenom_in: "ERROR",
                            nom_in: "ERROR",
                            password_in: "ERROR",
                            courriel_in: "ERROR",
                            userdigit: "ERROR"
                    }

                    ,errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                            container.append(error.clone());
                            error.insertAfter(element);
                    }

            });
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will find the documentation for the meta option in http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

If you want to display the errors beside the inputs **AND** in a separate error container you will need to override the `errorPlacement` callback.

From your example:

```
...
                    courriel_in: "ERROR",
                    userdigit: "ERROR"
            }
            ,errorContainer: container

            ,errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                var errorClone = error.clone();
                container.append(errorClone);
                error.insertAfter(element)              
            }

            // We don't need this options
            //,errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container)
            //,wrapper: 'li'
            //,meta: "validate"
    });
 ...
```

The `error` parameter is a jQuery object containing a `<label>` tag. The `element` parameter is the input that has failed validation.

## Update to comments

With the above code the error container will not clear errors because it contains a cloned copy. It's easy to solve this if jQuery gives a "hide" event, but it doesn't exist. Let's add a hide event!

1. First we need the [AOP plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AOP)
2. We add an advice for the hide method:

   ```
               jQuery.aop.before({target: jQuery.fn, method: "hide"},
                   function(){
                       this.trigger("hide");
                   });
   ```
3. We bind the hide event to hide the cloned error:

   ```
           ...
           ,errorPlacement: function(error, element){
               var errorClone = error.clone();
               container.append(errorClone);
               error.insertAfter(element).bind("hide", function(){
                   errorClone.hide();
               });
           }
           ...
   ```

Give it a try

Comment: Doesn't work because when the error is removed the error in the container still stay there. But you gave me some good input... +1

Answer (score 17):

First your container should be using an ID instead of a class.. (I'm going to assume that ID is 'containererreurtotal')

Then Try this..

```
    $().ready(function() {

        $('div#containererreurtotal').hide();

        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#frmEnregistrer").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: "#containererreurtotal",
            wrapper: "p",
            errorClass: "error",
            rules: {
                nickname_in: { required: true, minLength: 4 },
                prenom_in: { required: true, minLength: 4 },
                nom_in: { required: true, minLength: 4 },
                password_in: { required: true, minLength: 4 },
                courriel_in: { required: true,  email: true },
                userdigit: { required: true }
            },
            messages: { 
                nickname_in: { required: "Nickname required!", minLength: "Nickname too short!" },
                prenom_in: { required: "Prenom required!", minLength: "Prenom too short!" },
                nom_in: { required: "Nom required!", minLength: "Nom too short!" },
                password_in: { required: "Password required!", minLength: "Password too short!" },
                courriel_in: { required: "Courriel required!", email: "Courriel must be an Email" },
                userdigit: { required: "UserDigit required!" }
            },
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                $("#containererreurtotal").show();
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                if (this.numberOfInvalids() == 0) {
                    $("#containererreurtotal").hide();
                }
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
            }    

        });
    });
```

I am assuming here that you want a <p> tag around each of the individual errors. Typically I use a <ul> container for the actual container (instead of the div you used called 'containererreurtotal') and a <li> for each error (this element is specified in the "wrapper" line)

If you specify #containererreurtotal as display: none; in your CSS, then you dont need the first line in the ready function ( $('div#containererreurtotal').hide(); )

Comment: Thanks FerrousOxide,
your answer helped me too. :)

Comment: Thanks FeO - unhighlight is the callback I was looking for to check the outstanding invalid items.  Jackpot!

Comment: @DarthJon it took me FOREVER to get back to see this. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 6):

I would remove the errorContainer and then intercept the validation on postback and in there add a container-error manually like this:

```
$("#frmEnregistrer").bind("invalid-form.validate", function(e, validator) {
  var err = validator.numberOfInvalids();
  if (err) {
    container.html("THERE ARE "+ err + " ERRORS IN THE FORM")
    container.show();
  } else {
    container.hide();
  }
}).validate({ ... })
```

Comment: Ok this is the effect I want for the container, still one problem is the container display because if I want the ERROR next to the control, I have to use "Serhii" code and it remove the formating inside the container...

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly different solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var submitted = false;
  var validator = jQuery("#emailForm").validate({ 
      showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
          if (submitted) {
              var summary = "";
              jQuery.each(errorList, function() {
              summary += "<li><label for='"+ this.element.name;
              summery += "' class='formError'>" + this.message + "</label></li>"; });
              jQuery("#errorMessageHeader").show();
              jQuery("#errorMessageHeader").children().after().html(summary);
              submitted = false;
          }
          this.defaultShowErrors();
      },          
      invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { submitted = true; },
      onfocusout: function(element) { this.element(element); },
      errorClass: "formError",
      rules: { 
          //some validation rules 
      },
      messages: { 
          //error messages to be displayed
      }           
  }); 
});
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for when I found this post.  All I had to do was add 'invalidHandler: function(form, validator) { submitted = true; },' to make my code work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with the following short code:

```
errorElement: "td",
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
     error.insertAfter(element.parent());
}
```

My structure is the following:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So my errors will now shown directly in a `<td>` behind my `<input>`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the validation plugin provides an option for this, but you can probably use standard jQuery to achieve what you want. Make sure you're container is initially hidden, by setting the display style to none:

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then you can hookup an onsubmit event to the form which will make the container visible as soon as an attempt is made to submit the form:

```
jQuery('#formId').onsubmit(function() {
    // This will be called before the form is submitted
    jQuery('#container').show();
});
```

Hopefully combining that with your existing code should do the trick.