# Validator.element() triggers a stackoverflow error when validating inside a jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that's displayed in several parts by using a jquery ui accordion widget.  I'm trying to create validation feedback so that if one of the accordion tabs contains any input that is invalid, that tab is highlighted (as is the input field).  This is easy for most of my tabs because they only have one input field per tab.  I do have one tab, however, that has two input fields under it.  Here's the way that I'm trying to tackle that problem:

```
//validation rules for new story form   
var storyValidator = $("form#new_story").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
            $("#story_create_warning").html("Your form contains " + storyValidator.numberOfInvalids() + " errors, see details below.");
        }).validate({
    ignore: [],  //so to perform validation on elements that have display:none
    errorClass: 'validationError',
    errorContainer: $("#story_create_warning"),

    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
         $(element).addClass(errorClass);
         $(element).parents(".accord_contents").prev()
                   .addClass(errorClass);
    },

    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        //because the story_contents accordion tab has more than one input on which to validate, 
        //only remove that tabs highlighting if all elements under the tab are valid
        if ($(element).hasClass("story_contents")) {
            var contentsArray = $(".story_contents");
            var length = contentsArray.length;
            for (var i=0; i<length; i++){
                if (!storyValidator.element(contentsArray[i])) { //don't remove tab highlight if even one element in the tab doesn't validate
                    return
                }
            }
        };
        $(element).parents(".accord_contents").prev()
                            .removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    rules: {
        "story[title]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 49
        },
        "story[posts_attributes][0][contents]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 399              
        },  
        "story[posts_attributes][0][photo]": {
            accept: "jpeg|jpg|png|gif|JPEG|JPG|PNG|GIF"             
        }
    },
    messages: { [my messaging]},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter( element.parent("div") );
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="new_story_form" class="removed" title="Create a New Story">
   <form action="#" method="post" id="new_story" autocomplete="off">
     <h4 id="story_create_warning" class="error" style="display:none;"></h4>

    <input type="hidden" name="story_centerpoint" id="hidden_story_location" />
    <div id='story_create_accordion'>

        <h3 class="story_accord_tab">Step 1 - Story Title</h3>
        <div class="accord_contents">
            <div class="field">
                <textarea id="story_title" class="story_title noScroll formWidthSmall" name="story[title]" placeholder="Insert a title for your story"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3 class="story_accord_tab">Step 2 - Story Contents</h3>
        <div class="accord_contents">
            <div class="field">
                <textarea id="contents_of_story" class="story_contents post_contents noScroll formWidthSmall" name="story[posts_attributes][0][contents]" placeholder="Insert your news"></textarea>
                <br/>
                <label>Add a photo</label>
                <input id="story_photo" class="narrowInput story_contents" type="file" name="story[posts_attributes][0][photo]"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3 class="story_accord_tab">Step 3 - Additional Options</h3>
        <div class="accord_contents">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Additional info:
                    <textarea class="story_options" name="story[extra_info]"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div> <a href="javascript:;" id="submit">submit</a>
```

This works just fine on all of the elements that don't belong to the `story_contents` class.  I can also perform `storyValidator.element("#[enter element id]")` on those elements.

Things breakdown, however, with elements that belong to the `story_contents` class.  For those elements, If I insert a value that doesn't conform to my validation rules the `highlight` method triggers just fine. When I insert text that conforms to my rules the `unhighlight` method triggers, and then, after a several second delay, the browser crashes.  I tried setting a breakpoint in the middle of the `for` loop inside of the `unhighlight` method, and then use the console to execute `storyValidator.element("#contents_of_story")`.  The console returns the following error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  I'm having some sort of recursion problem, but I sure can't figure it out.

Here is the fiddle showing the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Td8C/4/).  The browser doesn't crash when running the fiddle, but you can see the delay, and see that the unhighlight method doesn't remove the highlight as it should.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks go to @Sparky for all the time he spent trying to help me.  As he pointed out, my code is verbose, and weeding your way through it can be difficult.

But still, there are plenty of examples on the web of people initializing the Validate object just like I do, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285428/jquery-validation-how-to-display-error-container-only-when-submitting) and [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-any-doc-on-the-validator-object-in-the-invalid-form-validate-event). So, I didn't think that was my problem.  Also, the [API Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) show an example of using `highlight` and `unhighlight` to address a need similar to mine.  So, I thought that keeping my `highlight/unhighlight` overrides was the way to go.  So, what was the problem with my `unhighlight` override?

In the middle of the night I suddenly realized why I was experiencing the `stack overflow` error.  Inside my `unhighlight` method I used the `Validate.element()` method.  That method triggered a new validation on the just validated element.  That validation attempt passes and then triggers `unhighlight` on that same element, which then recursively attempts to validate the element again.  This unintended loop resulted in the `stack overflow` error.

The solution was to not use the `elements()` method, but instead to look at the `invalidResults` object generated by the immediately previous validation attempt to see if either of two elements that I needed to inspect continued to be invalid.  If either of those elements had tested-out as invalid, then I knew to keep the highlighting on the parent tab.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Td8C/7/) shows the solution at work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the Accordion. Even disabling it you still have the issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Td8C/6/

However, your jQuery Validate initialization is all wrong...

```
var storyValidator = $("form#new_story").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
        $("#story_create_warning").html("Your form contains " + storyValidator.numberOfInvalids() + " errors, see details below.");
    }).validate({ ... });
```

`.validate()` can only be attached to a `form` element... and not chained to anything else.

Properly initialize the plugin like this instead:

```
$("form#new_story").validate({ ... });
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/3Td8C/5/

Comment: good catch on this not being an accordion issue.  I'm not too sure that the initialization is the problem, though.  If I change the initialization to what you recommend then I'm not able to reference the validation object in the unhighlight method.  So, your fiddle appears to be working, but it's actually throwing an error in the for loop: `Uncaught ReferenceError: storyValidator is not defined `.  So, it never ends up hitting the `storyValidator.element(contentsArray[i])` method.

Comment: @chuckw, `var storyValidator = $("form#new_story").validate({ ... });`  would also be acceptable.  (My answer was meant to point out the single major cause of your problem; I'm confident you can make it work from here.)

Comment: thanks for helping me with this issue.  I should've been more clear with my last comment.  I did use `var storyValidator = $("form#new_story").validate({ ... });`.  And, with the `storyValidator` variable being initialized, execution once again passed to the for loop where `storyValidator.element(contentsArray[i])` triggers the overflow error, just as it did prior to removing the chaining.  Your fiddle appeared to work, but it actually never got to the `element` method.  Any other ideas, or am I really being dunce here?

Comment: @chuckw, let's back-up and simplify things here.  Forget about the accordion for now.  Explain exactly what you're trying to do with that method.  I have a hunch things are way more verbose than they need to be.

Comment: I'm sure your right about my code being verbose.  Normally I wouldn't touch the `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods.  I'd just let the validator do its thing.  In this case, however, I want to turn off highlighting of an `<h3>` element only if both the `input` and `textarea` that appear within the following `div` pass validation.  If either element fails validation, then I want to continue to highlight the `<h3>` element.

Comment: @chuckw, sounds like this whole thing was approached from the wrong direction.  `highlight` and `unhighlight` are the callback functions which toggle along with the status of the element's validation.  Why not write a custom rule/method instead and just let the `highlight/unhighlight` function as intended?

Comment: @chuckw, I also don't think this is a valid approach: `.bind("invalid-form.validate")`.  Where exactly does the `invalid-form.validate` event come from?

Comment: it doesn't seem like the event is documented, but it does exist.  See, https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-en/4Nn6QrK0hy8